# PostgreSQL 10 Constraint across 2 columns?

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

Is it possible to add a constraint that checks that TWO columns are unique in PostgreSQL 10? I've looked around but I can't find anything related to my specific need.

My issue is that I have to keep track of individual IDs (tag), associated to secondary IDs (hub). I can't set my tag IDs to be unique because they'll appear multiple times associated to hub IDs. I also can't set hub IDs unique because they'll have a bunch of tag IDs associated to them.

Is there a way to say (tag 123 and hub 456) unique, but tag 123 can still be logged if hub is 789, and vice versa?

The root of this is because the ON CONSTRAINT DO UPDATE doesn't seem to work without unique constraints, and I'm now stuck.

References, solutions, other related problems that were solved, any help is appreciated!

Comment: just add a unique key on both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

indexes can be on multiple columns

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX name ON table (tag,hub);
```

[11.6. Unique Indexes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-unique.html)

Comment: I LOVE YOU. Thanks.

Comment: As can [table constraints](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html). `CREATE TABLE (..., UNIQUE (tag,hub))`

Answer (score 2):

You need to define a [primary key](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-PRIMARY-KEYS) made of those two columns. This way you can have two or more rows in your table with the same value on the first column of the primary key, but different values on the second column, and vice versa.

Also, if you don't already, you can use [pgAdmin](https://www.pgadmin.org/), which is a visual tool that helps you create a database and defining tables, columns, data types, constraints, primary keys, etc. with an easy user interface.

Comment: does not need to be primary, unique is a better idea here

Comment: I see, maybe the primary key is already taken for another column/group of columns

Comment: Primary key is actually better, IMHO if the pair of columns is the only natural key. Otherwise, it could be an ordinary UNIQUE constraint.